# Wine: exe file build with electron creates error "Bad EXE format"

Tags: electron, wine

i've got an exe file called presentation.exe that was build with electron. i am running the 32bit version of wine (4.0) which should be fine.

when i'd like to run the exe file using wine i get the error

```
Bad EXE format for presentation
```

this error message does not really help me at all in debgging the problem. how can i get a bit more information and/or solve this issue?